# What is a New Grad Rotational program?

Tags: work-experience, new-hires, student, fulltime

Many IT companies offer this type of job opportunities for new grads to gain working experience, which is good.

But will it always lead to a full-time position after completing the program. If not, what are the chances that these young people could earn a full-time position?

Edit: assuming I want to keep working for the company when the period ends.

Comment: We need more info here. Do you want to continue doing IT? Do you want to work for that company after the rotational period?

Comment: Voting to close as these programs will be different from company to company.

Answer (score 1):

> But will it always lead to a full-time position after completing the program. If not, what are the chances that these young people could earn a full-time position?

Maybe. Every company will have slightly different implementations.

My company has an IT rotational program (as well as marketing/engineering/etc). You are considered a full-time employee throughout the duration of the program and effectively guaranteed a permanent spot after the program.

However, you may not get the spot you want - business conditions and availability of positions, etc.

Ultimately the way to learn this is to talk with the companies offering it. Ask what the transition process looks like. If they have a clear plan, you will learn - if not, you won't get a good answer. There isn't a unified "all companies do this" plan out there to follow. Everyone will have their own version of it.